# Slick slider slickAdd added multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, append, slick.js

I have a layout which has a question with 4 options. Onclick any answer it adds a new slide and goes to that slide.

```
$(document).on('click', '.goal1 li', function(e){
    $(this).addClass('goal-selected').siblings('li').removeClass('goal-selected');
    $('.slider').slickAdd('<div class="goal2"><h1>Question 2</h1><ul class="goals"><li>Option 1</li><li>Option 2</li><li>Option 3</li><li>Option 4</li></ul><div>');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.slick-next').trigger('click');
    }, 500);
});
```

Using this code. if I click on previous button and change the answer one more extra slide gets added with same property.

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/1ghon3fr/)**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/56Lvfe8e/)

```js
$(".slider").slick({
   infinite:false,
   draggable:false,
   useTransform: true,
   speed:900,
   cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)',
   easing: 'ease',
   edgeFriction: 20,
   touchMove:false,
  });
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(e){
    var Cclass=$(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('class').split('_')[1].split(' ')[0];
    var newCclass=parseInt(Cclass)+1;
    
    if(!$(this).siblings('li').hasClass('goal-selected'))
    {
    var addhtml='<div class="goal_'+newCclass+'"><div class="goals-setter"><h1>Question '+newCclass+'</h1><ul class="goals"><li>Option 1</li><li>Option 2</li><li>Option 3</li><li>Option 4</li></ul></div></div>';
 $('.slider').slickAdd(addhtml);
  
    }
    $(this).addClass('goal-selected').siblings('li').removeClass('goal-selected');
 movenext();
});
  
    
    function movenext()
    {
    setTimeout(function(){$('.slick-next').trigger('click');}, 500);
    }
```

```css
.slider {
    width: auto;
    margin: 30px 50px 50px;
  }
  .slick-slide {
    background: #3a8999;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
    text-align: center;
  }

  .slick-prev:before,
  .slick-next:before {
    color: black;
  }

  .slick-dots {
    bottom: -30px;
  }

  .slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #e84a69;
  }
  *{
   box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  ul.goals{
   padding:0;
  }
  ul.goals li{
   list-style:none;
   float:left;
   width:50%;
   border:1px solid #fff;
   padding:20px;
   cursor:pointer;
  }
  .slick-slide{
   padding:0 30px 30px;
  }
  .qNav{
   margin-top:30px;
   padding:20px 40px;
  }
  .goal-selected{
   background:tomato;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.3.13/slick.min.js"></script>


<section class="slider">
  <div class="goal_1">
   <div class="goals-setter">
    <h1>Question 1</h1>
    <ul class="goals">
     <li>Option 1</li>
     <li>Option 2</li>
     <li>Option 3</li>
     <li>Option 4</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: Thanks Rony, it works well but I want every questions to be different not just question 1,2,3 in loop. So I have tried something with your fiddle. Just see. How can I achieve this. https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/56Lvfe8e/1/

Comment: May it help! [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/56Lvfe8e/3/#&togetherjs=HwcqyJODBI)

Comment: Onclick last question options it was giving error because there is not any objects and click event is calling the next object. I have given an if condition `if($('.slider ul').length < 5)` and 5 one it will just add a class not other methods will not be called. Am i right?  https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/56Lvfe8e/5/